# How long does it take for Ariane 5 to roll to the launch pad?

Tags: launchpad, ariane

The launchpad is 2800 m away from the building where Ariane 5 is assembled. Based on the [Ariane 5 user manual](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Ariane5-users-manual-Jun2020.pdf), Section 7.5.5, Figure 7.5.5.4.b, the Ariane 5 transfer to launchpad happens one day before the launch. How long does it take for Ariane 5 to go from hangar to launchpad?

Comment: [Merely seconds apparently ;)](https://youtu.be/Df1pMZ-Lqfs), but that video could be a place to start coupled with knowing that the launch tables have ["a maximum speed of 4 km/h"](https://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet79/dalmau79.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the upcoming JWST launch - which is presumably representative - the rollout will take a couple of hours:

> Ground crews at the jungle spaceport in French Guiana planned to transfer the European Ariane 5 rocket with the Webb telescope on top to the ELA-3 launch zone Wednesday.
> That rollout, expected to take about two hours, has been delayed to Thursday.

([Spaceflight Now](https://spaceflightnow.com/2021/12/21/launch-of-webb-telescope-delayed-to-christmas-morning/))